# Is a player of one sport allowed to play in another sport?

Tags: international-sports

Michael Jordan played baseball, though he is a well-known basketball player.
Can a (professional) player of one sport play (professionally) in other sports?
Have any other players done so?

Comment: Your question is a valid one if you mean can an athlete play multiple sports AT THE SAME TIME. But note that there is nothing stopping athletes from just switching from one sport to another, and that must have happened to a lot of athletes. In the case of Michael Jordan which you used as example, he stopped playing basketball, pursued baseball for couple of years and then came back to the NBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example:

1. [Sir Vivian Richards](http://www.rediff.com/sports/slide-show/slide-show-1-fifa-world-cup-fifa-5-facts-that-bind-cricket-and-the-football-world-cup-vieri-viv-richards-bucknor-mexican-wave-moore/20140625.htm) (West Indian Cricketer) played Football World Cup

> **Sir Viv Richards**, the legendary West Indies batsman, had sublime footballing skills.He wasn’t just any footballer, but the only player
>   to play in the football and cricket World Cups.The legendary batsman
>   represented Antigua in the qualifying rounds of the 1974 football
>   World Cup.

2. [Ellyse Alexandra Perry](http://www.womenfitness.net/ellyse_perry.htm) (Australian Cricketer) played Football World Cup

> **Ellyse Alexandra Perry** (born 3 November 1990) is an **Australian sportswoman** who made her debut for both the *Australian cricket and
>   football teams* at the age of 16. She played her first cricket
>   international in July 2007 before earning her first football cap for
>   Australia a month later. Perry is the youngest person, male or female,
>   to represent Australia in cricket and the first Australian woman to
>   have appeared in both cricket and association football World Cups.

Comment: -1 for plagiarism and uncited material:  http://www.rediff.com/sports/slide-show/slide-show-1-fifa-world-cup-fifa-5-facts-that-bind-cricket-and-the-football-world-cup-vieri-viv-richards-bucknor-mexican-wave-moore/20140625.htm http://www.womenfitness.net/ellyse_perry.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A player is allowed to play more than one sport.

Some of the well-known sports persons who play in more sports are:

**Baseball**

Sammy Byrd – won six PGA Tour events after retiring from baseball

**Basketball**

Nathaniel Clifton – played baseball in the Negro Leagues, before becoming the first African American to land a NBA contract.

**Boxing**

Adam Hollioake – Turned professional as a boxer in 2011 having captained the England ODI side in the 1990s. He subsequently turned professional at MMA

**Chess**

Sir George Thomas, 7th Baronet was twice British Chess Champion and a 21-time All-England Badminton champion.

**Cricket**

**Stuart Broad** - also played field hockey as a goalkeeper until 17, trialled for England

**Don Bradman** - won the South Australian squash championship

Johnny Douglas - England cricket captain and Olympic champion boxer

**AB de Villiers** - South African cricket who still holds six national high-school records in swimming. Also excelled in badminton, tennis, golf, hockey, rugby and football.

**Jonty Rhodes** - South African cricketer who was chosen as part of the national hockey team in the 1992 Olympic Games

**Swimming**

Jehan Mubarak(Srilanka) started his sporting career as a swimmer and then became a cricketer.

For full list [visit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multi-sport_athletes) here